# Gremlin-Visualizer not displaying local graph

Tags: node.js, gremlin, ontology, tinkerpop

I am trying to display a small (455 node) TinkerPop/Gremlin graph created on my Mac running Big Sur (11.6) through Gremlin Console (3.4.8) on a local TinkerPop server (3.5.1) using Gremlin-Visualizer recently cloned from https://github.com/prabushitha/gremlin-visualizer (e7c4f46).  Previously (6 months ago) I had no problem displaying much larger graphs but now nothing is being displayed after following the README and issuing:

- npm install
- npm start

where gremlin-visualizer is running on localhost:3000 and gremlin server on localhost:8182 which as noted can successfully access from gremlin console.

In the server, I execute

bin/gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-graphs-server.yaml

in which yaml file, in graphs, I declared the "skills_small" graph configured in conf/tinkergraph-graphs-empty.properties (wherein vertexIdManager=ANY), and in ScriptEngines, declared ScriptFileGremlinPlugin to br configured in scripts/gremlin-graphs.groovy (wherein TraversalSource "a" is bound it to "skills_small" graph).

I execute query a.V() in said browser window (localhost:3000) with host set to localhost and port set to 8182.  Nothing happens, no display, no message.  Have tried a few different modifications (like using IP address, running npm run client instead of npm start) to no avail.

Am moving onto graph notebook but I really like gremlin-visualizer as a stand-alone node app for presentation purposes and the attractive graph.

Also, I have brew installed Python 3.9.8 (and have installed pyenv (2.2.0) and soft-linked to brew Python but am not running all of this software under a virtual environment).  Don't want to go Docker either.  Also brew installed npm.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider opening an issue at https://github.com/prabushitha/gremlin-visualizer as this seems very specific to some sort of configuration issue with the tool. I suspect that is a more likely place to find the creator of the tool. You could also try asking on the Apache TinkerPop Discord channel at https://discord.com/channels/838910279550238720/838910279550238723

Comment: I actually started there, Kelvin, and got no response so thought I would try here.  Not going to bother anyone anymore on this.  Have actually started in on your graph-notebook and that works just as advertised.  Thank you for all your work  supporting development on property graphs - the one true ontology platform.